# When two perpendicular lines are rotated about each other (out of their common plane), what is the new angle between them?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, solution-verification, euclidean-geometry, rotations

When two perpendicular lines are rotated about each other (out of their common plane), what is the new angle between them?

More formally: Let $\ell, m$ be two perpendicular lines, and let their common plane be $P$.  Rotate $\ell$ about $m$ out of plane $P$ by angle $\theta$, and rotate $m$ about $\ell$ out of plane $P$ by angle $\phi$.  Now $\ell'$ and $m'$ have common plane $Q$.  What is the angle $\psi$ between $\ell'$ and $m'$?

*Source: This question arose from the comments to [Prove the hyperbolic paraboloid $xy = z$ intersects its tangent plane in two perpendicular lines](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4727786/prove-the-hyperbolic-paraboloid-xy-z-intersects-its-tangent-plane-in-two-per) .*

My solution is below.  I request verification and, if possible, further simplification or analysis.

Potentially related: [Determining new coordinates after a rotation of a sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378925/determining-new-coordinates-after-a-rotation-of-a-sphere) and [New angle formed after rotating pipe](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1544734/new-angle-formed-after-rotating-pipe) .

---

WLOG, assume $\ell$ and $m$ intersect at the origin, $\ell$ includes $(1,0,0)$ and $m$ includes $(0,1,0)$.  Then $\ell'$ includes the origin and  $(\cos \theta, 0, \sin \theta)$ and $m'$ the origin and $(0, \cos \phi, \sin \phi)$.  The angle $\psi$ between them is $$\begin{align}\psi &= \arccos \frac{\ell' \cdot m'}{\|l'\|\|m'\|} \\
&= \arccos (\sin\theta \sin \phi).
\end{align}$$

I'm not able to simplify further (other than noting that the above equals $\arccos (\frac 1 2 [\cos (\theta - \phi) + \cos(\theta + \phi)])$).

The above shows that if only one line is rotated, they'll remain perpendicular ($\sin 0 = 0$), but if both are rotated (excluding null rotations), they will never remain so.

Comment: Could you please draw a figure?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I'm not capable of drawing a three dimensional figure.  If you have a suggestion on how to do so, please share it.  The idea should be simple:  Take two sticks and place them flat on a piece of paper, crossing perpendicularly.  Rotate one around the other, so that it's end comes off the paper.  Do the same for the other.

Comment: Hint: rotations preserve angles and distances.

Comment: @KurtG. While rotations of the _entire space_ preserve angles, rotations of individual lines of course do not.  So can you explain how your hint is relevant?

Comment: When we rotate $\ell$ about $m$ then the angle between $m$ and $\ell$ does not change. If we subsequently rotate $m$ about (the new) $\ell$ their angle does not change. If you have a different understanding of rotation please clarify.

Comment: @KurtG. I think the issue may be: I intend (and believe I wrote) to rotate $m$ about **the original $\ell$**, whereas your argument refers to rotating $m$ about **the rotated $\ell'$**.  Do you concur? How should this best be clarified and approached?

Comment: @SRobertJames If you leave one line fixed and rotate the other out of the plane, the angle is preserved because the fixed line is the center axis of a cone and the rotated line stays on the cone. Each line on that cone makes the same angle with the fixed line.

Comment: Why does the rotated line stay on the *same* cone? Imagine closing a pair of scissors holding one blade still. As the moving blade rotates, the angle between the blades decreases. (If you want to be sure $m$ is rotating “out of the plane [containing $\ell'$ and $m$, I guess],” use loose right-handed scissors with your left hand.)

Comment: @SteveKass If the scissor blades get closer together then they are being rotated within the same plane.

Comment: @JohnDouma The blades probably won't stay in the same plane if you use loose scissors with the wrong hand. (Aim the moving blade’s point not directly to the fixed blade’s point, but a bit to the side.)

Comment: @SteveKass I see what you mean. I think a better image may be that of a sun dial. The piece that sticks out of the face remains fixed while the shadow moves in the plane defined by the dial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t have any disagreement or suggestions on your solution, but I wanted to point out that (consistent with your solution), the answers and comments that say the lines remain perpendicular are wrong for the question you asked, which  involves rotating two lines independently out of the same plane that contains them before rotation. (This is not the same as rotating one line out of $P$ and then rotating the other line out of a plane that is not $P$.)

Suppose $\ell$ and $m$ are the $x$- and $y$-axes of standard three-dimensional space. Then the plane $P$ is the $xy$-plane.

If you rotate the $x$-axis out of $P$ (the $xy$-plane) by $90^\circ$, it becomes coincident with the $z$-axis. If you rotate the $y$-axis out of $P$ (the $xy$-plane) by $90^\circ$, it also becomes coincident with the $z$-axis.

The $x$ and $y$ axes are perpendicular, but after each is rotated $90^\circ$ out of the $xy$-plane, they become coincident and the angle between them is zero.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\boldsymbol{m}$ and $\boldsymbol{\ell}$ are originally perpendicular we can place the coordinate axes w.l.o.g. such that $\boldsymbol{m}$ is the unit vector on the $x$-axis and $\boldsymbol{\ell}$ is unit vector on the $y$-axis. Rotating $\boldsymbol{\ell}$ about $\boldsymbol{m}$ by the angle $\theta$ (counterclockwise) takes $\boldsymbol{\ell}$ to
$$
\boldsymbol{\ell}'=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0\\\cos\theta\\\sin\theta\end{smallmatrix}\right)\,.
$$
Rotating $\boldsymbol{m}$ around the original  $\boldsymbol{\ell}$
by the angle $\phi$ gives
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{m}'&=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}\cos\phi\\[1mm]0\\[1mm]\sin\phi\end{smallmatrix}\right)\,.
\end{align}
The cosine of the angle between $\boldsymbol{\ell}'$ and $\boldsymbol{m}'$ is therefore
$$
\boldsymbol{\ell}'\cdot\boldsymbol{m}'=\sin\theta\sin\phi\,.
$$

Comment: This is true, but in the question, $m$ is rotated about the original $\ell$.

Comment: @SteveKass Correct. I revised the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is *this* the figure you have in mind?

[image]

You can't put a figure in a comment, so please don't downvote this.

Comment: Thank you.  That looks very good (with $\ell$ red and $m$ blue), although it's hard to tell which one of the choices is $\ell'$ and $m'$.

Comment: Please see my comment to the main question, that $m$ is to be rotated about the **original** $\ell$, not the _rotated_ $\ell'$.  Does the diagram capture that?

Comment: Look up "Euler angles."

Comment: Can't put a figure in a comment.